# Jquery Clone Submits Form After Cloning

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, html

First I am new to jquery and javascript

```
<link href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:400,500,700' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
<link rel='stylesheet' href='http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css'>
<script src='http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js'></script>  
  <form action="test.php">
     <div>
      <div id='realElements'>
        <input type="test" name="test">    
      </div>

      <div id="clonedElements">
        Cloned
      </div>
      <button type="submit">
        submit
      </button>

       <button id="cloneButton" type="script">
      Clone
      </button>
  </div>
</form>
    <script>
      $("form").on("submit", e => e.preventDefault());
       $(document).ready(function() {
      $("#cloneButton").click(function(){
        $("#realElements").clone().appendTo("#clonedElements");
      });

});
</script>
```

Here is my code to clone the `text element`

Actually it works by referring to `@Jack Bashford` answer.

As

```
$("form").on("submit", e => e.preventDefault());
```

but I can't submit the form.

Here is my requirement: I want to clone as much of element and submit the `form`

Answer (score 1):

Two solutions to this:

One: remove the `<form>` element. This is by far the easiest, and it's not being used for anything as far as I can tell, so it shouldn't break your page.

Two: add an event handler for the form submission that stops submission. This one's simple too, just add this code:

```
$("form").on("submit", e => e.preventDefault());
```

Comment: i can't remove the form tag because its a student registration form

Answer (score 1):

The reason why the clone button submits is because any button tag within a form that does not have a `type` attribute (or in your case having an invalid `type`, `type="script"` and `type="test"` are invalid) is considered a `type='submit'`.

In the demo I removed:

```
$("form").on("submit", e => e.preventDefault());
```

Then I added a button with a valid `type='button'` and another button with nothing, You wanna guess which one submits when clicked?

```html
   <link href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:400,500,700' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
<link rel='stylesheet' href='http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css'>
 
  <form action="test.php">
     <div>
      <div id='realElements'>
        <input type="test" name="test">    
      </div>

      <div id="clonedElements">
        Cloned
      </div>
      <button type="submit">
        submit
      </button>

       <button id="cloneButton" type="script">
      Clone
      </button>
      
        <button type="button">
      type='button'
      </button>
      
        <button>
      type=null
      </button>
      
  </div>
</form>
<script src='http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js'></script> 
    <script>
     
       $(document).ready(function() {
      $("#cloneButton").click(function(){
        $("#realElements").clone().appendTo("#clonedElements");
      });

});
    </script>
```

Comment: you have clearly explained my requirement and it worked

Comment: I used to have the same problem when I started developing, I learned the hard way.

Comment: can you solve my issue @[ link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54106476/jquery-clone-clones-a-wrong-div-element)

Answer (score 0):

The button by default without explicit declaration of the type assumes the role of submit. Thus when you trigger a click it submits the form [Button w3.org](https://www.w3.org/TR/2011/WD-html5-20110525/the-button-element.html)

> The missing value default is the Submit Button state.

You have the following solutions

- convert the button to link (a tag).
- define the type of the button
- place the event inline in the element and return false at the end

Alternatives where you will lose the default behavior of the form

- preventDefault on the form via javascript
- add inline attribute onsubmit="return false;" on the form element

An example with inline attribute

```
<button id="cloneButton" onclick="$('#realElements').clone().appendTo('#clonedElements');return false;">Clone</button>
```